# delegate all subsequent call to another object reference

Tags: groovy

I have a method, which requires a certain class as a parameter.

```
def walkOver(IWalker instance) {
    def list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    list.each {
        instance.enterItem(it)
        if (it.isOdd()) {
            instance.enterOdd(it)
            instance.exitOdd(it)
        } else {
            instance.enterEven(it)
            instance.exitEven(it)
        }
        instance.exitItem(it)
    }
}
```

Basically I iterate over a list and do certain operations with its elements.

Class `IWalker` looks like this

```
class IWalker {
    void enterItem(item) { }
    void exitItem(item) { }
    void enterOdd(item) { }
    void exitOdd(item) { }
    void enterEven(item) { }
    void exitEven(item) { }
    void enterCommon(item) { }
    void exitCommon(item) { }
}
```

I've got two primitive subclasses of `IWalker` which do only a certain task

```
class OddWalker extends IWalker {
    void enterOdd(item) {
        println "Odd: $item"
    }
    void exitOdd(item) {}
    void enterCommon(item) {}
    void exitCommon(item) {}
}

class EvenWalker extends IWalker {
    void enterEven(item) {
        println "Even: $item"
    }
    void exitEven(item) {}
    void enterCommon(item) {}
    void exitCommon(item) {}
}
```

Also I have a composite walker - which should delegate operations to instances of corresponding `IWalker` implementation

```
class CompositeWalker extends IWalker {
    @Lazy def oddWalker = new OddWalker()
    @Lazy def evenWalker = new EvenWalker()

    def currentRef = this // default

    void enterItem(item) {}
    void exitItem(item) {}

    void enterOdd(item) {
        currentRef = oddWalker
        currentRef.enterOdd(item) 
    }

    void exitOdd(item) {
        currentRef.exitOdd(item)
        currentRef = this
    }

    void enterEven(item) {
        currentRef = evenWalker
        currentRef.enterEven(item)
    }
    void exitEven(item) {
        currentRef.exitEven(item)
        currentRef = this
    }

    void enterCommon(item) {
        if (currentRef == this) {
            // code
        } else {
            currentRef.enterCommon(item)
        }
    }
    void exitCommon(item) {
        if (currentRef == this) {
            // code
        } else {
            currentRef.enterCommon(item)
        }
    }
}
```

I want my `CompositeWalker` to delegate all subsequent calls of the methods inside `walkOver` method to corresponding object.

Currently I store a reference to the current object and just invoke its methods.

Ideally I would like to do something like this

```
class CompositeWalker extends IWalker {
    @Lazy def oddWalker = new OddWalker()
    @Lazy def evenWalker = new EvenWalker()

    void enterItem(item) {
        if (item.isOdd()) {
            // delegate all IWalker calls to oddWalker
        }
    }
    void exitItem(item) {
        // return to current object
    }
}
```

There I do not implement methods of `oddWalker` and `evenWalker` inside `compositeWalker` at all.

Is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the @Delegate annotation, you can get rid of the implementation of the Common methods.

```
class CompositeWalker extends IWalker {

    @Lazy IWalker oddWalker = new OddWalker()
    @Lazy IWalker evenWalker = new EvenWalker()

    @Delegate
    IWalker currentRef = this // default

    void enterItem(item) {}
    void exitItem(item) {}

    void enterOdd(item) {
        currentRef = oddWalker
        currentRef.enterOdd(item)
    }

    void exitOdd(item) {
        currentRef.exitEven(item)
        currentRef = this
    }

    void enterEven(item) {
        currentRef = evenWalker
        currentRef.enterEven(item)
    }
    void exitEven(item) {
        currentRef.exitEven(item)
        currentRef = this
    }
}
```

Comment: So it will reference to current reference in `currentRef` when invoke `common` method?

Comment: Yes, it will call any method on the delegate, that is not overriden in `this`

Answer (score 1):

To me, something is off about your code. Notice that you're calling `isOdd()` twice: in `walkOver()` and in the `CompositeWalker`. So you're essentially making the same decision twice. Also, the even/odd pair in the `IWalker` and their corresponding even/odd implementations are a clue that there may be a flaw in the way you're using strategy pattern.

While having `CompositeWalker` delegate to an appropriate `IWalker`, I think there's a better way; according to my understanding of your code. I propose a refactoring which uses a factory to choose an appropriate walker, and letting the walker do it's thing with complete disregard for whether the item is even or odd; because the choice would have been made already. So here it goes:

```
def walkOver(IWalkerFactory factory) {
    def list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    list.each {
        def walker = factory.get(it)

        walker.enterItem(it)        
        walker.exitItem(it)
    }
}

interface IWalker {
    void enterItem(item)
    void exitItem(item)
    void enterCommon(item)
    void exitCommon(item)
}

interface IWalkerFactory<T> {
    IWalker get(T obj)
}

abstract class AbstractWalker implements IWalker {
    void enterItem(item) { }
    void exitItem(item) { }
    void enterCommon(item) { }
    void exitCommon(item) { }
}

class OddWalker extends AbstractWalker {
    void enterItem(item) {
        println "Odd: $item"
    }
}

class EvenWalker extends AbstractWalker {
    void enterItem(item) {
        println "Even: $item"
    }
}

class WalkerFactory implements IWalkerFactory<Number> {
    @Lazy IWalker oddWalker = new OddWalker()
    @Lazy IWalker evenWalker = new EvenWalker()

    IWalker get(Number number) {
        if(number.isOdd()) oddWalker
        else evenWalker
    }
}
```

In a nutshell, `walkeOver()` asks the `IWalkerFactory` to return an `IWalker` that's appropriate for the item. The `IWalkerFactory` implementation is the only code that cares about even/odd. Then, `walkOver()` simply calls the methods on the `IWalker` returned by the `IWalkerFactory`.

A benefit of this approach is that it removes the need for a `CompositeWalker` which is a fusion of strategy and state machine. If you can avoid using a state machine, a future developer will thank you.

Comment: Actually I do not have access to `walkOver` method (I imitated the behaviour of another library) so I cannot change it.

Comment: Yes I too found the structure a little odd, but suspected that this was not intentional.